# Combinatorial generating function networks

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, neural-networks

I am working through the following [paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/604/1/012013/pdf) (ref 1), and do not understand how to generate equation 6.

The generating function for the degree distribution of a network is

$$
G_0(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_kx^k
$$

The probability that $i$ of the $k$ edges of a node are occupied is given by the binomial distribution

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
k \\
i
\end{pmatrix}
x^i (1-x)^{k-i}
$$
If we select a node at random then the probability of $i$ of it's edges being occupied is 
$$
\sum^\infty_{k=i} p_k 
\begin{pmatrix}
k \\ 
i
\end{pmatrix}
x^i (1 - x ) ^{k-i}
$$
So far so good. Now, I do not understand how this becomes
$$
\frac{(-x)^i}{i!}\frac{d^i}{dx^i}G_0(1-x)
$$
**References**

[1](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/604/1/012013/pdf) Li, Wang. Generating function technique in complex networks. Journal of Physics: Conference Series 604 (2015) 012013

Comment: $d^{i}/dx^{i}(1 - x)^{k} = (-1)^{i}\frac{k!}{(k - i)!}(1 - x)^{k - i}$ for $k \geq i$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
G_0(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k x^k.
\end{eqnarray*}
differentiating $i$ times gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^i}{dx^i} G_0(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k  \frac{k!}{(k-i)!} x^{k-i} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Now substitute $ x \rightarrow 1-x$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
(-1)^i \frac{d^i}{dx^i} G_0(1-x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p_k  \frac{k!}{(k-i)!} (1-x)^{k-i} .
\end{eqnarray*}